# Python Format String with List

Tags: python, string

I want to format a string in Python, and as one element have every element of a list, for example below

```
mylist = ['john','phil','ted']
var1 = 'xxx'
var2 = 'zzz'
'{0} bla bla bla {1} bla bla {2}'.format(var1,<every item in mylist>,var2)
```

Basically what I am after is

```
xxxx bla bla bla john phil ted bla bla zzz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) all the strings in the list and pass like this

```
>>> mylist, var1, var2 = ['john','phil','ted'], 'xxx', 'zzz'
>>> '{0} bla bla bla {1} bla bla {2}'.format(var1, " ".join(mylist), var2)
'xxx bla bla bla john phil ted bla bla zzz'
```

Comment: Hi thefourtheye, yes this worked for me perfectly. I couldn't find an exact similar question on stack so thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 2):

I find `%` more concise than `format`.

```
'%s bla bla bla %s bla bla %s' % (var1, ' '.join(mylist), var2)
```

As already stated, you can `join` every item in `mylist` to turn it into a string.